# How can I send password safely to tmux?

Tags: passwords, zsh, tmux

The following is my code in create_tmux.zsh

```
#!/bin/zsh

SESSIONNAME=$1
echo $SESSIONNAME
tmux has-session -t $SESSIONNAME &> /dev/null

if [ $? != 0 ]
then
    tmux new-session -d -s $SESSIONNAME -n emacs
    tmux new-window -t $SESSIONNAME:1 -n a
    tmux send-keys -t $SESSIONNAME:1 'ssh -Y a@bc.com;$2' C-m
fi

tmux attach -t $SESSIONNAME
```

It's simple if I run

create_tmux.zsh ab $%^^&av1@

But in this way, it not only shows in the terminal of my password but also recorded in history.
How can I solve this?
Thank you

Comment: Use `read -s` to read password. Search for `read [` in http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html, and pay attention to the `-s` option: "Don’t echo back characters if reading from the terminal." For instance, try the following for yourself: `read -s 'password?Password: ' && echo -E $'\n'"Your password is: $password"`.

Comment: Use public key authentication so that you don't have to provide a password at all. Then you can drop `send-keys` altogether, just passing `ssh -Y a@bc.com` as arguments to the `new-window` command.

Comment: @chepner I run this command on the local server and I ssh another server in the shell. Then I need to create key in the local server and add it to the another server. Am I right? Is there any tutorial to do this? Thank you

Comment: Right; once you've generated the key pair on the local server, the private key stays on the local server and the public key goes to the remote server.

Comment: @chepner Thank you very much. I do this, but this time it shows `Enter passphrase for key '/home/***/.ssh/id_rsa':`. Asking for the ssh key password. Then I use `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` . It works. Thank you very much